# API to API - With a Service Account

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4, clientcredential

I am trying to call an API (API2) from another API (API1) with the help of client credentials flow. Is it possible to grant access to only some parts of API2?

To give some context, When making call from API1 to API2, I am currently using a service account that decides what parts of API2 are allowed access. The service account is created and configured (with roles) in API2 and shared with API1 ahead.

I am trying to achieve this same with oAuth's client credential flow but I could not find any information on restricted access inside API. I believe ApiScopes won't work in this case.

Could you let me know if restricted API access is possible in client credentials flow? or can this be achieved in any other flow?

Regards,
Siva

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the built in authorization system in ASP.NET Core to control access based on the claims inside the received access token. what **AddJwtBearer** do is to convert your access token (once authenticated) into a **ClaimsPrincipalUser** object.

See these links for details:

- [Policy-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0)
- [Claims-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, we can define a new Application Role for the API2. This role will have access to selected parts of the API2. Then we can add this role to the Client_id you are using in Client Credentials flow.